# .Net Threadpool tasks not cleared when service is stopped

Tags: c#, .net, service, threadpool

I have a service that continuously adds thread tasks to a ThreadPool by calling ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(blah); When I want to update the service, I stop the service, uninstall, reinstall the newer version then restart the service.  When all of this happens, I would expect that the ThreadPool would be clear of all the old tasks that hadn't had a chance to execute before this update happens.  However, this does not seem to be the case since when the service starts back up, it tries to continue from where it left off and execute the old tasks. Is this the wrong assumption to have? What would cause the old tasks to remain in memory?

Comment: Please tell us more about this service. If it's a separate process, then you should indeed get a separate thread pool. It sounds like you're not actually killing the process.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your response. The service itself just pretty much runs (applicationName).exe as a separate process. The service and exe gets reinstalled using an msi and I do see logs from MsiInstaller that says "Product: (applicationName) -- Removal completed successfully" which I assume to mean that the exe was removed cleanly which would also mean the process should be dead too.

Comment: Get a verbose uninstall log and look for entries from the Restart Manager. Is there anything that was detected to be still running and/or removal was deferred?